# fadeIn li one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of some item, i want fadeIn element one by one, means if first element complete fadeIn then next element fadeIn and so on, in my given code what going wrong i dont know, please help me..

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ulfade"><li>ABC</li><li>ABC</li><li>ABC</li><li>ABC</li></ul>
```

**JS**

```
var i=0;
$('#ulfade li:nth-child(' + i + ')').fadeIn(500, function () {
     $('#ulfade li:nth-child(' + (++i) + ')').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/suUHD/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
$('#ulfade li').each(function(key, value) {
    $(value).delay(key * 500).fadeIn(500);
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Pj2/)

**Edit**

As you changed your fiddle, here's a solution that works when hovering some other element:

```
$('#divFade').mouseover(function() {
    $('#ulfade li').each(function(key, value) {
        $(value).delay(key * 500).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $(this).unbind();
});
```

**Demo 2**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/vktsz/)

Comment: please try it in fiddle

Comment: my fiddle change see it

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using `delay` by doing the following:

```
$('#divFade').mouseover(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var list = $('#ulfade li');
    (function displayLI() {  
         list.eq(i++).fadeIn(500, displayLI);  
    })();  

    $(this).unbind();
});
```

This uses the completion callback to iteratively fade in the next item in the list.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/vktsz/2/)